apt update from terminal shows following pakages are upgradable but i am not able to upgrade them
I have attached screenshot for the same also i am not able to upgrade as it always shows packages can't be upgraded. i got 2 warnings as shwon in the image please help! 

Please don't post screenshots of terminal output, instead, copy the terminaloutput and paste it as text into your question, thanks.

Consult the output that you posted. There is a clear indication on which third party repository is causing the problems. Contact the owners to have their repository fixed, or remove that repository from your system.
